# Удалить первую строку вместе с переносом строки в txt

Tags: bat

Есть файл. Содержимое файла:

```
UUID                                  
031B021C-040D-05BA-7E06-970700080006
```

Необходимо удалить скриптом bat вот это — "UUID".
Чтоб осталось только вот это на первой строке:

```
031B021C-040D-05BA-7E06-970700080009
```

Comment: Отметить, нажать `Delete`, затем сохранить `Ctrl+S`.

Comment: Да, это забавно. Но надо скриптом в bat файле это сделать)

Comment: Добавте это прямо в вопрос, чтобы он не выглядел забавно.

Comment: Исправил уже\\\\\

Comment: У вас в файле только 2-е строчки?

Comment: Да. Всего две. Необходимо чтоб осталось только одна с цифрами

Comment: [**У меня работает вот это решение**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432438/5951529). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Решение

Из возможных решений выбрал [**такое**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432438/5951529), чтобы работало c нативными командами Windows. Команды Linux и/или прочее дополнительное ПО на Windows устанавливать не нужно.

`bat`-файл состоит из 2 строк.

```bat
more +1 "SashaUUIDeal.txt" > "SashaTemporary"
move /Y "SashaTemporary" "SashaUUIDeal.txt"
```

Где:

- `SashaUUIDeal.txt` — имя Вашего файла,
- `SashaTemporary` — временный файл, который создастся и сразу же удалится в процессе выполнения скрипта; можно назвать его как угодно.

---

### 2. Описание команд

#### 2.1. more

1. `more "SashaUUIDeal.txt"` — выводит в консоль содержимое файла `SashaUUIDeal.txt`.
2. `+1` — вывод в консоль производится без без первой строки. `+4`, например, означало бы, что выведется содержимое файла без первых четырёх строк.
3. `> "SashaTemporary"` — запись текста, который выводится в консоль, в файл `SashaTemporary`. Произвести запись в тот же файл `SashaUUIDeal.txt` без временного файла не получается, придётся задействовать ещё одну команду.

#### 2.2. move

1. `move "SashaTemporary" "SashaUUIDeal.txt"` — перемещение содержимого файла `SashaTemporary` в `SashaUUIDeal.txt`. Файл `SashaTemporary` при этом удалится.
2. `/Y` — перезапись файла (в данном случае `SashaUUIDeal.txt`) без предупреждения.

---

### 3. Дополнительно

1. [**Справка по команде `more`**](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/more.html),
2. [**Справка по команде `move`**](http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/move.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
nhrt.exe -sre:".*\r\n" -occ:1 -e -o:d file.txt
```

Удаляет первую строку из файла. Автоматическое определение кодировки. Но потребуется скопировать exe.